# Getting null values from GetEigenDistances Function

Tags: c#, image, emgucv

I am trying to compute the distance of images in Emgu.CV using the `float[] GetEigenDistances(Image<Gray, Byte> image)` method.

However I keep getting null values in the distance array. This is the code I have so far:

```
float[] dist = GetEigenDistances(image);///function call all images are of same sizes

public float[] GetEigenDistances(Image<Gray, Byte> image)
{
    using (Matrix<float> eigenValue = new Matrix<float>(EigenDecomposite(image, _eigenImages, _avgImage)))
        return Array.ConvertAll<Matrix<float>, float>(_eigenValues,
            delegate (Matrix<float> eigenValueI)
            {
                return (float)CvInvoke.cvNorm(eigenValue.Ptr, eigenValueI.Ptr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.NORM_TYPE.CV_L2, IntPtr.Zero);
            }); 
}
```